# Installing mingwrt into the haskell-platform without mingw-get

Tags: windows, haskell, mingw, haskell-platform

The haskell-platform (2014.2.0.0) ships MingGW, but without mingw-get. However, to compile the setlocale bindings for haskell I need locale.h, which is part of mingwrt.

In a usual mingw installation I would use mingw-get to install mingwrt, but since it's not included in the haskell-platform that doesn't work out of the box.

What would be the usual way of installing mingwrt without mingw-get?

Comment: You should use the steps given over and over again if one wants to have a msys with haskell. https://gist.github.com/Jonke/cccd567ed78d7a612810

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about install of software not related to the actual problem.

Comment: @Jonke No, the help center says "If your question generally covers… •a specific programming problem, or •a software algorithm, or •software tools commonly used by programmers; and is •a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" That's a yes because of points 3 and 4.

Comment: @Jonke Okay. I (once again) noticed that I totally misinterpreted the problem. It's not really the case that mingwrt is not installed (which would have been strange from the beginning) but that the locale.h in mingwrt lacks LC_MESSAGES, which I interpreted as not having locale.h installed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Install MSYS[^1]

```
Download version 1.0.11 of MSYS. You'll need the following files:

MSYS-1.0.11.exe

msysDTK-1.0.1.exe

msysCORE-1.0.11-bin.tar.gz

The files are all hosted on haskell.org as they're quite hard to find in the official MinGW/MSYS repo

Run MSYS-1.0.11.exe followed by msysDTK-1.0.1.exe. The former asks you if you want to run a normalization step. You can skip that.

Unpack msysCORE-1.0.11-bin.tar.gz into D:\msys\1.0. Note that you can't do that using an MSYS shell, because you can't overwrite the files in use, so make a copy of D:\msys\1.0, unpack it there, and then rename the copy back to D:\msys\1.0.
```

[^1]:[Setting up a Haskell development environment on Windows](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/01/setting-up-haskell-development.html)

Comment: How is this related to mingw-get?

Comment: @Kritzefitz I suppose you are using windows? (and not cross-compiling on linux/mac). Then you need a base for development and that base are the steps provided. Then you can get more things to compile that uses external libraries. If my assumption isn't correct you need to give a concrete example, what library are you trying to use from haskell?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. You're also right that I need a development base. But for installing the needed libraries (in this case mingwrt) I expect to have mingw-get. But the development base you're describing just doesn't contain mingw-get. And that's what the question is about. So the question could be reworded to "How do I get mingw-get into my development base?", but I think the current title is much more descriptive.

Comment: mingw-get is used to install packages into your mingw, so what packages do you need to integrate with haskell ? Since you are gonna use something with haskell the package for that are already in the mingw that ships with the haskell platform. So, once again, what library are you trying to compile and use from haskell?

Comment: I want to compile the setlocale package (because I need it for my own project) and need (as said in the last comment) mingwrt, because it contains locale.h.

Comment: So, you want to FFI a library (static or dymaic) from haskell but you can't compile the library? I suggest you take a step back and think about what you actually are asking. But in short, compile your library however you want, after that take the library and the header files and use the standard haskell FFI.

Comment: You're right. I've had too much assumptions about how it should work. I reworded the question to ask for my specific problem instead of another I assumed to be the solution. I hope it's now clearer what I'm trying to do. Sorry, for arguing for such a long time.